# How can validate either one of the textfields to be filled in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. Now in my form I have two fields FirstName and LastName.
I want to validate such that either of the two is filled. i.e not both should be empty.
Suppose the user leaves both the fields empty it should not allow submit. The user should atleast enter any of these fields.
**Rules**

```
public function rules()
        {
                return array(

                        array('Firstname,Lastname, email, subject, body', 'required'),
                        array('email', 'email'),
                        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
                );
        }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use beforeValidate() for this
In your model make a method

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
$firstName=trim($this->firstName);
$lastName=trim($this->lastName);
if(empty($firstName) && empty($lastName))
{
$this->addError('firstName','Please Enter your name');
}
return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct but why the `rtrim(trim(...))`. Isn't `trim()` the equivalent of `ltrim(rtrim(...))`?

Comment: @topher sorry it was a mistake. thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function rules()
  {
    return array(
      array('Firstname,Lastname', 'oneOfTwo', 'Firstname', 'Lastname'),
    );
  }
  public function oneOfTwo($attribute,$params)
  {
    $valid = false;

    foreach ($params as $param) {    
      if ($this->$param !== NULL) {
        $valid = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if ($valid === false) {
      $this->addError( $attribute, 'Your error message' );
    }
  }
```

Comment: look at [**THIS**](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22651-validation-rule-at-least-one-of-three-fields-is-filled/)

Answer (score 0):

In model

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('field1, field2', 'required')
    );
}
```

Action in controller

```
$model = new Model;

if (!empty($_POST['Model'])) {

    $model->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Model');

    if ($model->validate())
        $model->save();
}
```